# .htaccess https Edit for anything after url also

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This sounds like it should be very simple...  Trying to add `https:` if not defined on a url that has a string including and after `page=postratingspro` or `page=paypaltest`

Here's the code I'm using, with the help of someone here at stackoverflow:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=(paypaltest|postratingspro)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)page=(paypaltest|postratingspro)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Am looking at this `[&\s]` and `(&|$)` so wondering how this would need to change to include any strings at all?  So it should also change the protocol to `https` for the url if this url was defined:  http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=postratingspro;sa=thankyou
But if it's already set at `https` it shouldn't change it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how "any" you mean.

Should the following line change to HTTPS?

http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=postratingsprothankyou

If so, then just delete the "[&\s]" (which means "the next thing is an ampersand or white space"). Omitting it means you don't care what comes next.

If it should only change if "postratingspro" is a separate word, followed by maybe punctuation or something, then replace the "[&\s]" with "\b" (which means "word boundary"). I recommend this.

And the same with the "(&|$)" (which means the next character is a & or the end of the string) - I recommend replacing with "\b".

Comment: Yay, glad to have helped. My first green tick! :D